# How to link ws2_32.lib in Clion？

Tags: c, clion

I am new to C Winsock programming and Clion with MinGW.
I know that MinGW don't link Winsock library (which is Ws2_32.lib) automatically.I need to manually tell compiler by using -l flag plus name of my library.How can I manually add compiler flags in Clion?

Comment: This [FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/) suggests they use CMake exclusively so you probably want to edit your `CMakeLists` file.

Comment: What should I add to my CMakelists file?